# Pattern for specialization of generic class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, generics

In C# I sometimes wish I could make special methods for certain "instantiations" of generic classes.

**UPDATE: The following code is just a dumb example of a more abstract problem - don't focus too much on time series, just the principles of "adding extra methods" for certain T**.

Example:

```
class Timeseries<T> 
{ 
    ...
    TimeSeries<T> Slice(...) { ... }
}
```

In the case where T is double, I would like some extra methods, like `Integrate()`, `Interpolate()` and so on that make only sense for `double`, because I need to do arithmetic on them.

There are several ways to do this, but I cannot find one that I'm satisfied with.

**1. Inherit into a special class**

```
class TimeseriesDouble : Timeseries<double>
{ 
    double Interpolate(...) { ... }
    ...
}
```

**cons:** `TimeseriesDouble.Slice()` will return a new `Timeseries<double>` object, now missing my special methods.

**2. External methods**

```
public static double Interpolate(Timeseries<double> ts, ...) { ... }
```

**cons:** Breaks with OO principles. And I don't want to put my methods away. Also, the methods might need private/protected state.

**3. Extension methods**

Same as 2, just with a nicer calling syntax.

**4. Common base class**

```
class TimeSeries_base { ... }
class TimeSeries<T> : TimeSeries_base { .. typesafe versions of methods .. }
class TimeSeriesDouble : TimeSeries_base { .. typesafe versions of methods .. }
```

**cons:** too much duplication of things from `TimeSeries_base` into the two subclasses. The base class might become just a place holder for utility functions for the sub classes.

**pro:** I can now do things like `List<TimeSeries_base>` dynamically.

**5. Just forget about a common class**

I.e., keep `Timeseries<T>` and `TimeseriesDouble` separate in the code.

**cons:** Then I don't get all the benefit of treating a `TimeseriesDouble` like a `TimeSeries<T>`, e.g. combining two timeseries with ZIP(A,B), where one happens to be of doubles.

---

**Any other ideas?**
Currently, I think I like the design (1) best.

Comment: It might be useful to give more concrete examples of the client code you have, as well as what a TimeSeries is. If you don't, you'll get a lot of off-topic answers because there's not enough information to go on, and people will make assumptions.

Comment: for example, I don't understand why (2) can't return TimeSeries<double>, or if that's valid, why I can't have public static T Interpolate(Timeseries<T> ts, ...) { ... }, etc. Can I have a TimeSeries<AnyOldClass>?

Comment: Yes, maybe the examples should be more concrete.

But I think of this as just an example of a more general design problem. So maybe I should express the problem more abstractly, so that TimeSeries don't disctract from the essense?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could always use the self-referential generics trick:

```
public class TimeSeries<T, U> where U : TimeSeries<T, U>
{
    U Slice(...)
}

public class TimeSeriesDouble : TimeSeries<double, TimeSeriesDouble>
{
    ...
}
```

It can get a bit brain-bending, but it can work.

Comment: In my concrete library I think I'll go for something more straight-forward. Nice trick, though, I'll keep it in my bag :-)

Comment: but there would still be a problem if you want to extend `TimeSeriesDouble`. Then, the subclass' `Slice` method would return a `TimeSeriesDouble` and not an instance of the subtype. I'd use F# and pattern matching for handling this kind of structures.

Answer (score 9):

```
interface ITimeSeries<T> { ... }

abstract class TimeSeriesBase<TS> where TS : TimeSeriesBase<TS> 
 { public TS Slice() { ... } 
 }

class TimeSeries<T>:TimeSeriesBase<TimeSeries<T>>,ITimeSeries<T> {}

class TimeSeriesDouble:TimeSeriesBase<TimeSeriesDouble>,ITimeSeries<double>
 { public double Interpolate() { ... }
 }
```

Comment: Perfect! This is just what I was thinking.

Comment: That's the pattern I use as well.

Comment: What are the benefits of using this approach instead of this one posted by Jon Skeet? It's nearly the same, isn't it?

Comment: With this approach, you can treat both `TimeSeriesDouble` and `TimeSeries<double>` as an `ITimeSeries<double>` which is kind of what the OP wanted, e.g., to `Zip` together.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with (1) and cast as appropriate.

```
 TimeSeriesDouble tsD = new TimeSeriesDouble();
 TimeSeriesDouble subTSD = tsD.Slice(...) as TimeSeriesDouble;
```

Comment: Yes, I like a solution like that. Caveat: .Slice() (a method in TimeSeries<T>) now has to actually return a TimeSeriesDouble, so it must be virtual or use other tricks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider implementing a factory to return the appropriate subclass.